# Detecting SQL Server Utilization with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

My current project will send queries to an sql server constantly and It may use 100% of the memory or CPU.

- How can I check if the server is nearing full utilization in a stored procedure so that I can decide whether to execute the queries or not or save some settings in a table so that the following queries can know the workload is high and decide what to do
- If not, how can I prevent SQL server to reach full utilization?

More information about the case: 
Right now I know our current test server can process 40-50 queries per second (one specific stored procedure). And now we'll decide how many queries are sent to the server every second. If we set the amount even 1 higher than the expected, in the long run, the queries will eventually fill the virtual memory and out client will have to restart their sql server instance periodically.

Expected Results (For bounty hunters):

```
@memory_usage float, @cpu_usage float; /* in percentage */
```

Any ideas are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Based on your question I think I would step back and look at an alternate approach.

Comment: First if you’re using up the virtual memory on your server make sure that your instance has the max memory setting set.  SQL Server is fairly good at managing it's cache memory so you should never need to re-start the instance (for this particular problem) unless you are taking memory that the OS needs to function.  There are lots of articles out there on how much memory to leave the OS, but you could start by looking at BOL here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx.  It's 2012 but I'm not sure what version you are using.

Comment: Next you could look into a service broker approach.  Load your SP requests into a queue and then set the queue to execute them x wide.  Where x is the number of SPs you want running at the same time.

Last but not least you could look into resource governor.  This will let you break your resources apart so that certain types of operations are only allowed so much memory and/or CPU.  BOL is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx.

Answer (score 7):

Would something like this help you?

[Script To Monitor Memory Usage By SQL Server Instance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsakthi/archive/2011/02/28/t-sql-script-to-monitor-memory-usage-by-sql-server-instance.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

For any such intensive use of SQL Server and effort to fine tune it, I assume that the (virtual) machine is dedicated to SQL Server.

Having said this, getting the machine's current percentages of CPU and memory used should do the trick:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_GetSystemUsage
    @cpuUsage float out,   -- % CPU usage
    @memoryUsage float out -- % memory usage
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*
     * % CPU usage
     */

    SELECT TOP 1
        @cpuUsage = 100 - r.SystemIdle
    FROM (
        SELECT
            rx.record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id,
            rx.record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS SystemIdle
        FROM (
            SELECT CONVERT(XML, record) AS record
            FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
            WHERE
                ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' AND
                record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%') AS rx
        ) AS r
    ORDER BY r.record_id DESC

    /*
     * % memory usage
     */

    SELECT
        @memoryUsage =
            (((m.total_physical_memory_kb - m.available_physical_memory_kb) /
              convert(float, m.total_physical_memory_kb)) *
             100)
    FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory m
END
```

A few things to note:

- `sys.dm_os_sys_memory` is a good source for the machine's physical-memory usage.  It provides similar information about the machine's page-file usage.  In my experience, its information changes frequently - multiple queries against it within a second yielding different results.
- `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers` is a good source for the machine's CPU usage, but it is not updated as frequently - every minute from what I have seen.  Maybe you can affect this if you need more real-time information.
- The CPU-usage value in `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers` is an integer, but I made `@cpuUsage` a `float` per your spec.  Since the stored proc uses two `float` params, you could refactor CPU-usage determination to provide a fractional portion without changing its callers.

Comment: Glad to hear that the memory-usage check helps, @Uğur Gümüşhan.  In what way did the CPU-usage check not work?  Did it error?  Maybe a simple adjustment is required for it to work in your environment.  Also, that reminds me - what SQL Server and OS versions are you using?  (According to `@@VERSION`, I checked the stored proc on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 17 2011 00:57:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1).)

Comment: we have sql server 2008r2 in the company.. cpuusage returns 1 each time

Comment: Interesting, @Uğur Gümüşhan.  Thanks for the follow-up.  If you execute the query `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' AND record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%' ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC`, what values do you see for the `SystemIdle` element in the `record` column's XML?  On my system right now, for example, they are `88`, `94`, `86`, `90`, `94`, `93`, `88`, `92`, `84`, and `77`.  Are they all `1` on your server?  If so, do you see any values besides `1` if you check beyond the `TOP 10` records...or try to heavily load the CPU?

Comment: I see some records, systemidle 99 andprocess utilization = 0 in all of them

Comment: Cool.  Thanks, @Uğur Gümüşhan.  (I realized as soon as I awoke this morning that I somewhat reversed my thinking in my previous comment - i.e. meant and should have said `99` where I indicated `1` of course.  Sorry for any confusion that I may have spread in being tired and rushing to bed!) :P  So I would expect then that you will see `SystemIdle` values lower than `99` if you load your CPU; or do you expect that it is already loaded and these `99` values are inaccurate?  Also, `ProcessUtilization` being for SQL Server itself and equaling `0` means that apparently SQL Server is not very busy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do this in SQL but you can always create a function in C# and then make it available in your SQL Server as stored procedure using CRL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx